# I am trying to create two buttons: one that adds a circle to the web page and one that deletes a circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create two buttons: one that adds a circle to the web page and one that deletes a circle.

There can be no more than 5 circles on the stage. If the add button is clicked and there are five circles on the page, an alert will pop up that tells the user no more circles can be added.

```js
var circle = document.getElementById('#div');

$(function() {
    $('#buttonOne').on('click', addItem);
    $('#buttonTwo').on('click', removeItem);
});


function addItem(){

    if (circle > 5) {
        alert('You cannot add more than 5 objects');
    } else {
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    };

}

function removeItem(){

    if (circle== 0) {
        alert('You have not added anything yet');
    } else {
        $(this).remove();
    };
}​
```

```css
.circle {
    display: block;

    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;

    border-radius: 50%;

    transition: background-color 350ms;
    
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Add Circle" id="buttonOne"/>
<input type="button" value="Delete Circle" id="buttonTwo"/>
<div class="circle"></div>
<p></p>

<script src="week4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

There were a few flaws in your code:

1. When using `getElementById`, you should just give the id name, not the `#` character.
2. `this` does not refer to a circle in the `removeItem` function and hence won't work.
3. Appending `circle` variables to the body would create duplicate ids, which is not allowed per the HTML specification.
4. (minor flaw) `> 5` would allow 6 circles to be created, so you should change it to `>= 5`.
5. (just unneeded code) binding the functions on the buttons does not have to be inside `$(function(){});`, it works fine without. Spares you a bit of code. :)

I've fixed those flaws for you below. Since I noticed you're already using jQuery functions, I took the liberty of taking advantage of jQuery in my code too. It could of course be implemented without jQuery. :)

```js
$('#addButton').on('click', addItem);
$('#removeButton').on('click', removeItem);

function addItem() {
    var circles = $(".circle");
    if (circles.size() >= 5) {
        alert('You cannot add more than 5 objects');
    } else {
        $("body").append("<div class='circle'></div>");
    };
}

function removeItem() {
    var circles = $(".circle");
    if (circles.length == 0) {
        alert('You have not added anything yet');
    } else {
        circles.last().remove();
    }
}
```

```css
.circle {
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    transition: background-color 350ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="addButton">Add a circle</button>
<button type="button" id="removeButton">Remove a circle</button>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r2e3va1h/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function addItem() {
    var circle = $(".circle");
    if(circle.length >= 5) {
        alert('You cannot add more than 5 objects');
    } else {
        $('<div/>').addClass('circle').appendTo($('#body'));
   };
}

function removeItem() {
    var circle = $(".circle");
    if(circle.length == 0) {
        alert('You have not added anything yet');
    } else {
        circle.eq(0).remove();
    };
}

$('#buttonOne').click(addItem);
$('#buttonTwo').click(removeItem);
```

```css
.circle {
    background-color: blue;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    transition: background-color 350ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="buttonOne">b1</button>
<button id="buttonTwo">b2</button>

<div id="body"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are missing some stuff in your js.

getElementbyId function just needs the name of the ID as an argument. So skip the pound sign (#).

Also. You are comparing "circle" to 0. Circle is a ID. And for best practices if several elements should use same ID, you should use the class attribute instead. So you need to figure out how to get out a number from the variable circle in order to compare it to another number.